# I am deploying my laravel 5 application to server. But its not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am deploying my laravel 5 application to server. I have changed the environment file as following

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=b809vCwvtawRbsG0BmP1tWgnlXQypSKf
APP_URL=http://example.org
```

I have deployed the application inside a folder named workshop in my server. But when I type `http://example.org/workshop` it is redirected to `http://127.0.0.1/workshop/` and shows error. 
How Can I solve this problem?
Here is my directory structure:
[image]
[image]

Here is my index.php file

```
 <?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @Laracademy It's probably going to be "Connection Refused" because there is not a web server running on localhost.

Comment: I am not using localhost. I am running it inside a server. And an web server is running there. I have other php application (not using laravel) running too in the server

Comment: Let me add my directory structure

Comment: Did you update the `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` on index.php to `require __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';` and `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`?
`

Comment: Yes I have done that

Comment: I finally came to another strange problem. It shows 500 error while loading